When I click the "Edit Review" button connected to Django, it triggers an iframe and the console shows a "502 Bad Gateway" error
this is my views.py file
this is my script file
When clicking the "Edit" button, it triggers an iframe for the update review page. The issue arises when I create a tunnel through VSCode to check my project, as it does not work at that time. However, it functions correctly when running on the normal localhost at 127.0.0.1:8000.please somebody give solution for this problem
I've tried everything I can think of, but I still can't figure it out.
